# How to optimize 8ByteArrayToUInt64 function?

Tags: javascript, optimization, bigint

Currently I have this:

```js
function 8ByteArrayToUInt64(buf, offset) {
    return BigInt(buf[offset]) | (BigInt(buf[offset + 1])<<8n) | (BigInt(buf[offset + 2])<<16n) | (BigInt(buf[offset + 3])<<24n) | (BigInt(buf[offset + 4])<<32n) | (BigInt(buf[offset + 5])<<40n) | (BigInt(buf[offset + 6])<<48n) | (BigInt(buf[offset + 7])<<56n)
}

// buf is Uint8Array
```

This function is called too often and I'm looking for a way to make it go faster.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigUint64Array

Comment: What do you mean? `new BigUint64Array(buf.buffer)`? It took longer last time i measured.

Comment: @rodaba If you're calling `8ByteArrayToUInt64` very often on the same buffer, don't create the `new BigUint64Array` every time but do it only once. It then should be a lot faster to just access that view by index.

Comment: …although what you actually might need is a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) that will let you control the endianness

Comment: I see, I see. Thank you, kind lords!

Comment: By the way, does dataview copies the buffer?

Comment: No, it's a *view*

Comment: No, it's just a view into the buffer. Also, if you need real speed with 64-bit ints, you should look at using a wasm module.